# Golang. Функции в качестве параметров и результата

Tags: функции, golang

Прошу объяснить мне как это работает на конкретном примере.

```
// validator проверяет строку на соответствие некоторому условию
// и возвращает результат проверки
type validator func(s string) bool

// and возвращает валидатор, который проверяет, что все
// переданные ему валидаторы вернули true
func and(funcs ...validator) validator {
    // ...
}
```

Что должно быть в функции and и почему? Хочется понять как такие конструкции работают.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Сам разобрался, вопрос снимается.

Answer (score 0):

```
func and(funcs ...validator) validator {
    // ...
    return func(s string) bool {
        for _, f := range funcs {
            if f(s) == false {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Функция and() имеет тип validator, что по сути функция, поэтому в and() сразу возвращаем анонимную функцию func(s string) bool (так тип validator описан). Далее в цикле перебираем поступившие в качестве параметров функции и вызываем каждую с параметром s, как только получаем false, выходим. Как то так я эту конструкцию понял.

Comment: Комментарии писать не надо, дополнить вопрос можно кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1446965/edit).